# Should I scale my data before time series PCA?

Tags: time-series, pca, econometrics, feature-scaling

I am doing PCA on 22 time series. All the series are log transformed and in their stationary form. The plot of all the input series is given below.

[image]

My main aim is to forecast GDP. I noticed that performance drops when I scale them. I used python for PCA and it centers the data but doesn't scale. Based on the above summary statistics and based on the fact that the series are log transformed and in their stationary form, is it reasonable if I use **covariance matrix**(i.e. not scaling).

Comment: Often it is preferable to scale the features regardless of whether your aim is to interpret biplots or use the transformed data as features in another model. What is it that you're trying to accomplish with PCA?

Comment: @Galen My aim is to use the transformed data as features in another model. I noticed a significant drop in the test RMSE when I scaled the data and fitted the model. Is it necessary that the standard deviation of features to be equal to one prior to PCA or if all the features have similar variances, can I proceed to PCA without standardizing to gain unit variance?

Comment: Depending on the model, a drop in RMSE could be due to a change in scale rather than an improvement of model performance. I don't think it is 'necessary', but it can improve the stability of some training algorithms such as gradient descent when applied to neural networks.

Comment: @Galen thanks for your answer. For neural networks I performed standardizing. My problem here is for an OLS time series regression.